Failed to compile the .proto file in IntelliJ Idea
Here are some .protoc files. The directory structure is as follows:
my-project
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── resource            
│   │   │   └── exampleA.proto
│   │   │   └── exampleB.proto
├── pom.xml

and pom file as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <protoc.version>3.19.3</protoc.version>
        <protobuf.plugin.version>0.6.1</protobuf.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>${protoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>${protoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${protobuf.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- 工具版本 -->
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protoc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <!--默认值，proto源文件路径-->
                    <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</protoSourceRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <!--生成OuterClass类-->
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Now I want to compile it into .java file via maven built into IntelliJ Idea：

However, the following error occurs: protoc did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information


So guys, I have two questions:

How to solve the garbled characters in the error log?
How to solve this error?

Intellij Idea version is: IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3 (Ultimate Edition), and Maven version is: 3.9.9


Check whether IntelliJ IDEA is passing parameters like -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 when executing Maven tasks. Also, verify that the console encoding in IDEA is correctly set to UTF-8.
You can right-click the task, select Modify Run Configuration, and adjust options such as VM Options, Maven Options, and Java Options as needed.

Add the pluginArtifact information after , for example:
<pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.14.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>

NOTE: The specific version should be determined based on your environment.



I just added the parameters -Dfile.encoding= UTF-8-dsun.stdout.encoding = UTF-8-dsun.stderr.encoding =UTF-8 in VM Options，also confirmed that the console encoding format was utf-8, but it still doesn't work confirm1 confirm2

sure, I also add the pluginArtifact information after, but the result is still the same

Have you tried the example provided in the README of grpc-java? If that still doesn't work, I think there might be some errors in your proto file itself.

ok,I'll take a look at this example and check my proto file, thank you!
